# Is there a way I can pass a struct variable as an argument to a function? (C)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Edit:
(1) Title (- previous title: How can I assign the address of a pointer to an already-existing variable? -- resolve at bottom of message);
(2) 'In short';
(3) spelling / punctuation.

In short: I am trying create and then locate a struct on the heap (I want to save memory on the stack), and passing arguments into various functions to populate the struct. In previous projects I created a pointer to struct, allocated this on the heap using malloc, and finally passing the pointer as argument to functions - this worked perfectly. My question: can the same be done without the use of a pointer?

I am trying to store a struct in dynamic memory. I succeeded in a previous mini-project, but I used pointer-to-struct, and passed this pointer to all my functions. Now I am burning to know if I could simply omit passing the pointer and pass the variable struct itself into the function.

My current example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct s_text t_text;

typedef struct s_text
{
    int     letters;
// some more stuff
} t_text;


int main(void)
{
    t_text text;
    t_text *tp;

    tp = malloc(sizeof(t_text));
    //&text = tp; <-- this here I tried, but error (value required as left operand of assignment)
    return (0);
}
```

In the above code I allocate memory on the heap for the tp. This is the memory I'd like to use.
Now, on the stack, memory was reserved for (t_text) text. I would like to discard this and only use the heap.

`t_text &text = malloc(sizeof(t_text));`  <-- this may work in C++, i don't know, but in C definitely not.

In another post's discussion on NULL pointers, someone claimed in C++ that the address of a variable could point to NULL with the following code
    `int &x = *(int*)0;`
but this definitely is not appreciated by my compiler. In fact, I tried several things with the address of a variable, but each time I try to set eg `&text = (some address)` this error pops up:
**error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment.**

(link to the post I refered to: ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable/57492#57492 )

Below what I tried earlier (and works perfectly):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct s_text t_text;

void    fn_prompt_user(t_text *tp);
void    fn_calc_letters(t_text *tp);

typedef struct s_text
{
    int     letters;
// some more stuff
} t_text;


int main(void)
{
    t_text *tp;

    tp = malloc(sizeof(t_text));
    fn_prompt_user(tp);
    fn_calc_letters(tp);
    return (0);
}
```

To conclude this post with my question: Is there a way I can pass a struct variable
as an argument to a function, or should I just accept passing pointer-to-struct is the one and only way to go?

Thanks!

-- answer to previous title's question (How can I assign the address of a pointer to an already-existing variable?): Not possible.
Error: **error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment.**
When declaring a variable, it is placed in memory. This memory location can not be changed, and so if  `int a = 3;` a is an lvalue (location value) which can be changed (to eg. 4), but &a is unchangeable, therefor an rvalue (so is 3). So `&a = ptr_a;` will never work. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The address-of operator (&) does not result in an lvalue. And fyi, "this may work in C++" - no it won't, even with the added contexts where `&` can appear in C++. Finally, regarding your burning question: `t_test t;` then use `&t` as the function argument to both `fn_promt_user` and `fn_calc_letters` , is what I suspect you *really* seem to have disconnected on. No dynamic memory management required *at all*.

Comment: If you want to pass a struct to your function, why not pass a struct to your function? `void fn_promt_user(t_text t); ... t_text t; fn_promt_user(t);` I highly recommend getting a good C book.

Comment: “Is there a way I can pass a struct variable as an argument to a function” is a different question from “How can I assign the address of a pointer to an already-existing variable?”

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just pass `&text` to a function. There's nothing wrong with passing struct pointers.

Comment: @WhozCraig I confused this, so thanks for clarifying! Otherwise, I found no problem in passing pointers, was merely looking for an alternative and was wondering why &t could not be assigned an address. This is clear now. Thanks a lot for your response!

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. passing the struct would not save the struct on the heap. This may be a tiny project, but in the future with larger projects I don't want to waste too much space on the stack. Regarding a good book: I'v downloaded C Programming Lang by Kernighan and Ritchie. Ill dive into it first thing, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Cheatah The reason for not wanting to pass the struct like that is that I prefer it on the heap, rather than on the stack. I'm just experimenting right now, but one day there may be a point where it would be better to save memory on the stack as much as I can. Again, just experimenting as the concepts are rather new to me. So far, I think the best way is to create a pointer to struct, allocate it on the heap, and pass the pointers to the functions, as you said. Thanks

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes you are absolutely right... I have adjusted the post accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out. Please advise if you feel there is more to be adjusted. Thanks

Comment: If you want to pass the struct by value, pass it by value (then in the called function, a copy of the entire struct will be on the stack). If you want to pass the pointer, pass the pointer (then in the called function, only the pointer will be on the stack). You cannot mix the two methods. The caller may place the struct on the stack or on the heap in either case. It rarely makes sense to allocate the struct on the heap and then pass it by value, but it is definitely possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a struct to a function, like ....

```
int myfunc(t_text mytext) {....}
then ...
t_text thistext;
...
myfunc(thistext);
```

and this puts the entire struct onto the stack for the subroutine to use.
but the C language has no 'ref' feature like C++.

You can ...

```
tp = (t_text *)malloc(sizeof(t_text));
myfunc(*tp);
```

==

Your second example, passing pointers to objects, is a very conventional means of using structs in C.  It has the advantage of not needlessly copying structs to the stack, merely pointers.  It has the disadvantage of allowing functions to modify the objects that are pointed to. The latter problem can be remedied by declaring that the argument points to a const struct. Like:

void fn_promt_user(const t_text *tp) {...}

Comment: I hadn't considered passing a const pointer as argument, in cases the struct shouldn't be altered.. But in general, my aim was to manipulate the struct(s) in the functions, and I was looking for alternative ways to passing a pointer to struct, but this worked for me earlier, so I'll just keep with this. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 0):

> should I just accept passing pointer-to-struct is the one and only way to go?

Basically, yes.

C does not have "pass by reference" built into the language.  If you want to have a function populate or otherwise modify a struct for you (or any other object for that matter), passing a pointer is the normal and idiomatic way of doing that.  There is no real alternative, short of ugly macro hacks and stuff like that.